# adding an existing angular project into another one

Tags: angular

I have an angular project I want to sell online.

In order to achieve that my idea was to create a new project with a landing page, a payment method and a login page then add inside this new project a page where user can run the existing project I want to sell using a dedicated route.
Ideally both projects should be linked without having to be in the same folder.

Is there a way to achieve that? (I'm using v17)

Answer (score 1):

@Oscar is right, in the angular your can add sub-projects and build them separately as needed. Your folder structure will be next way:

```
app
 |-projects
 |-----|-project1
 |-----|-project2
 |-src
 |--|-app  (your login page here)
```

You can browse in this repository to see the full code structure together:
https://github.com/Scotty134/Angular-sub-apps-setup

Comment: Are we forced to use `ng generate application` or can we just can copy and paste folder?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it will require a bit of work. You will need to update manually angular.json. Second option is to create/generate an application with the same name as your project#1, then copy paste all components and else inside there. We did same thing for one of our applications, we moved existing project into multi-project solution.

Comment: @Thanks for your answer

Comment: Any idea how it can be done in v17 module are slowly disappearing from angular

Comment: I think I've managed to fix some bugs but know my problem is that when loading component the styles for example are not loading from the project folder so everything is broken

Comment: You might need to fix path to your styles and else after copy-paste. I don't have installed Angular 17 today, but I can try to make step-by-step instruction some time tomorrow.

Comment: [here is  another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77784150/how-to-run-multiple-projects-inside-one-angular-application) explaining my problem.If you are able to answer that this would be great.Thanks in advance