# How to run multiple projects inside one angular application

Tags: angular

I've managed using v17 to run multiple projects inside one angular application.

The problem now is that if I import `AppComponent` from `project 1` inside my parent `AppComponent` I don't get the global styles `project 1`.

My observations at this point are that running different projects inside one application is quite the same as having a folder per complex component but I still can't find a way to really run some entire separated projects ( with index.html and separate node_modules ) inside a single angular application.
Is there a way to achieve what I want or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You can check out NX https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using milti-app approach you need to remember that you **can't** have references from child app to your main app. It's rule #1

[image]

In case if you need to use some shared styles, components, services, etc. Then you need to create shared library and move your re-usable components there. It will still allow you to build each project separately, or build the main app including sub-projects.

CLI examples:

```
//build main application
ng build 
//build project1 only
ng build --project project1
//build project2 only
ng build --project project2

//run main application
ng serve
//run project1 only
ng serve --project project1
//run project2 only
ng serve --project project2
```

[image]

In case if you don't need to build project1 and project2 separately, then you can take easy route and put everything under 1 project:

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions, I can update the answer later.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I've managed to add in `styles` inside `angular.json` the styles from my child project.Now the problem I have is that compiler says `The same density styles are generated multiple times`any ideas?

Comment: Did you make your global styles unique? Or you have naming duplicates across the multiple projects?

Comment: naming duplicates

Comment: I assume you can drop the global styles inside of your child project and keep in the top level angular.json. When you build an application (child or parent, doesn't matter) it takes styles from the main angular.json as I remember.

Comment: Yes I could do that but that's  a pity I'm not able to link multiple style sheets without error messages.Thanks